# How to get TenantId of Connect-AzureAD from PowerShell Script running in Azure function (Dotnet Core)?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, powershell-core

I am trying to get TenantId from Connect-AzureAD that will be returned in the powershell script.

Below is the powershell script:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
$User = "test@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
$context = Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential
$tenantId = $context.TenantId.Guid.ToString()
[pscustomobject]@{
    user = $tenantId
}
```

The script works when executed as a PowerShell script alone. But when, I try to run in dotnet core, it seems to be empty.

```
public static string RunScript()
        {
            using (Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                myRunSpace.Open();
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    var imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources", "ConnectAzureAD.ps1");
                    string content = File.ReadAllText(imagePath);

                    ps.AddScript(content);
                    var piplineObjs = ps.Invoke();
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(piplineObjs.Count.ToString());
                    foreach (PSObject obj in piplineObjs)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.Properties["user"].Value.ToString());
                    }


                    return stringBuilder.ToString();
                }
            }

        }
```

I get the following error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The above function is invoked from a Azure Function. It is using Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK v6.2.7 and System.Management.Automation v6.2.7.

How can I get the tenant Id returned from powershell script in dotnet core?
Or how can I get tenant Id using code with just user's email and password?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get tenant id by request [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph api: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization`

In the response is of the api, we can find the `id`(which is the tenant id) in it:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks, I saw this, but in order to get access token, I will need to know the tenant ID.

Comment: @chiaDev Since you want to run powershell, why not create a function app(powershell) and run powershell script directly instead of run powershell in .net core ?

Comment: ah right! that didnt cross my mind. thanks!